# How can I convert isomorphic-fetch to axios?

Tags: javascript, node.js, api

I need to fetch data from my backend api with `axios`, but i have done for practice purpose with `isomorphic-fetch`. But now i need to convert `axios`

Here is my code:

```
import fetch from "isomorphic-fetch";
import { API } from "../config";

export const signup = (user) => {
  return fetch(`${API}/signup`, {
    method: "POST",
    headers: {
      Accept: "application/json",
      "Content-Type": "application/json",
    },
    body: JSON.stringify(user),
  })
    .then((res) => {
      return res.json();
    })
    .catch((err) => {
      return err;
    });
};
```

please anyone can convert data fetch with `axios`

Thank you.

Comment: What did you try? Something like `return axios.post(\`${API}/signup\`, user).then(({ data }) => data)` should work